# Restart supervisord in every 30 mins ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I need to restart my supervisor service in every 30 mins and I tried the following

```
sudo crontab -e


#restart supervisor in every 30 minutes to check if port are freezed

0,30 * * * *  service supervisor restart
```

When I check my supervisor on 11:31 AM I  saw the uptime > 28 Mins  which means the supervisor is not restarted . **I was expecting uptime 1 Minute as it was supposed to restart on 11:30 AM**

```
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 1552, uptime 0:28:08
meitrack                         RUNNING   pid 1551, uptime 0:28:08
socketio                         RUNNING   pid 1553, uptime 0:28:08
ulbotech                         RUNNING   pid 1550, uptime 0:28:08
vt06                             RUNNING   pid 1549, uptime 0:28:08
```

Is there anything I missed

Comment: Why in the world are you doing this?

Comment: I have one socket listener in supervisor which freezes when it is inactive for 30 mins so I need to restart supervisor, now I am doing it manually whenever the customer complains

Comment: Ok, well you should fix **that** problem. Restarting a process every 30 mins is insane.

Comment: I managed to restart the process , can you please tell me cons of doing that.

Comment: What you're doing is equivalent to changing out a car's engine each time you need new spark plugs, instead of just replacing the spark plugs. You're treating the symptom, not the problem. Put your energy into sorting out why your listener is freezing.